# Excel VBA - filter by date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA to filter a file.

I filtered it for Field 5 and 8 but i also want field 7 to filter for date - i want the file to show all lines that are today + 14 day and filter the rest.

thanks

```
Sub Filter()

'
   Sheets("CP").Select
    Range("a3:d" & Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Plan"

 Range("a3:d" & Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="No"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```
Range("a3:d" & Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=7, 
Criteria1:=">=" & Date(), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & Date() +14
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, i think that i was misunderstood. what i want to see in the end is all the dates that are before today +14 (and not only the today+14 days).

Answer (score 0):

i added

'   Range("a3:d" & Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=7,

Criteria1:="<=" & Date + 14, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & Date + 14 '

it seems to work.

thanks