# Autofilter in Excel using VBA based on date range the user has entered

Tags: vba, date, range, autofilter

Tl; dr: How can I use VBA to autofilter dates based on dates entered in two cells (one for start date and one for end date)?

I'm trying to autofilter with VBA in Excel. I have a dataset that contains multiple rows (that change in the amount of rows every day). Seeing how I can have a macro that would automatically delete out dates that are outside of a range that the user would enter in two cells (one for the beginning of the date range and one for the end of the date range). I have code that pulls the data from its source and formats it, but the code to delete out the rows that fall outside of the date range I don't have any at this time. The dates could constantly change, some are before the start date and some are after the end date.

For example, if a user enters a start date of 2/1/2019 and an end date of 3/1/2019, then the autofilter would delete any before 2/1 and any after 3/1. The following week may have a completely different start and end date, so it would need to come from the cells rather than the dates themselves entered in the code.

The goal is to eventually have a count of the number of dates that appear in this dataset within the date range given, so alternatively the data could remain unchanged and just have a count of those dates. However I'd like to avoid this as it will eventually go in a report and I don't want to confuse the readers of the report if it contains older dates/dates after the date range.

I mentioned in the first paragraph that the data may change. This is because the rows above the dataset may be deleted or have some added. I haven't tested this out but a solution I've seen is here, where the range would always be referenced correctly. https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/5-ways-to-create-a-dynamic-auto-adjusting-vba-range

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767043/excel-vba-autofilter-not-working-with-date-column

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522990/excel-vba-filter-by-date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820757/filtering-between-two-dates-in-excel-vba

Comment: You should really research these kinds of questions before asking for help. This is a popular question and thus, the answer already exists on this site on multiple threads! Try to implement any one of them and change it to fit your criteria. If you are having problems, come back with a question relating to specific code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - filter by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522990/excel-vba-filter-by-date)